# how to make installation file for the developed eclipse RCP project?

Tags: java

i am working in eclipse RCP, Any abody please tell me the process for making the installation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new *Product*. This is a configuration file (`something.product`) and "executing" this product description will create an archived or deflated installable RCP application.

You'll have to go through some editor pages for the `*.product` file and a dialog (where you can decide whether to create an archive or not). Consult the eclipse help on this keyword/topic for detailled information.

Comment: i have completed one full working module of budget. now please how do i make product of the module

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any simple answer to your question.  As Andreas_D said, you need to create a Product Confiuration file (*.product).  This is done by using the New Wizard from the File menu (File >> New >> Product Configuration ) and going through that wizard.  But to do that you need to know if your application is feature based or plug-in based.  Once you have the file created and saved you can usually export the product from the set of icons in the upper right, the first one runs your product from the IDE; the second one is used to debug the app; the third one is export button and the fourth is used to validate the product configuration.  Assuming that all is good you probably want that third one.